# Wordpress: JQuery conflict between 2 cutsom built plugins

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

So, I have created 2 plugins, each of which are loaded into a page, plugin1 -> regionpages (http://192.0.0.0/index.php/regionpages/) and plugin2 -> regionresults (http://192.0.0.0/index.php/searchresults/).

Plugin 1, and associated javascript:

```js
function initialize() {
    feedData();
    categoriesData();
}

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    initialize();

    jQuery('#CountryList').change(function(){
        var enableButtonTemp = jQuery('#CountryList').val();

        if (enableButtonTemp === null || enableButtonTemp === "null" || enableButtonTemp === "") { //Check to see if there is any text entered
            console.log(enableButtonTemp);
            
            jQuery('.enableOnInput').prop('disabled', true);
        } else if (enableButtonTemp !== null || enableButtonTemp !== "null" || enableButtonTemp !== "") {
            console.log("The value of countries is " + enableButtonTemp + " so the submit button has been made clickable.");
            
            jQuery('.enableOnInput').prop('disabled', false);
        }
    });

});

function feedData() {
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        console.log("feedData is successfully hit.");
        var serialized = jQuery('#MyForm').serialize();
        jQuery.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            async: false,
            url: gymRegions.ajaxurl,
            data:{action: "showcountries", makeselection: "getCountryList", serialized},
            success: function (data, status, error) {
                //alert(data.html);
                jQuery('#CountryList').append(data.html);
            },
            error: function (data, status, error) {
                alert("failed in feedData. The following data is being returned: " + data.html);
                console.log(data);
                console.log(status);
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    });
}

function categoriesData(){
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        console.log("categoriesData is successfully hit.");
        var serialized = jQuery('#MyForm').serialize();
        jQuery.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            async: false,
            url: gymRegions.ajaxurl,
            data:{action: "showcountries", makeselection: "categoriesList", serialized},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                 jQuery('#CategoriesList').append(data.html);
            },
            error: function (data, status, error) {
                console.log(data);
                console.log(status);
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    });
}

function getCities() {

    jQuery(document).ready(function () {

        console.log("getCities is successfully hit.");
        jQuery('#CityList').empty();
        jQuery('#TownList').empty();
        var countryVal = jQuery("#CountryList").val();
        var serialized = jQuery('#MyForm').serialize();


        jQuery.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            async: false,
            url: gymRegions.ajaxurl,
            data:{action: "showcountries", makeselection: "getCityList", countryID: countryVal, serialized},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                jQuery('#CityList').append(data.html);
            },
            error: function (data, status, error) {
                console.log(data);
                console.log(status);
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    });
}

function getTowns() {
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        console.log("getTowns is successfully hit.");
        var cityVal = jQuery("#CityList").val();
        var serialized = jQuery('#MyForm').serialize();

        jQuery.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            async: false,
            url: gymRegions.ajaxurl,
            data:{action: "showcountries", makeselection: "getTownList", cityID: cityVal, serialized},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                jQuery('#TownList').append(data.html);
            },
            error: function (data, status, error) {
                console.log(data);
                console.log(status);
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    });
}

function getUserIDs() {
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        console.log("getUserIDs is successfully hit.");
        var countryVal = jQuery("#CountryList").val();
        var cityVal = jQuery("#CityList").val();
        var townVal = jQuery("#TownList").val();
        var categoriesVal = jQuery("#CategoriesList").val();
        var serialized = jQuery('#MyForm').serialize();
        var url = window.location.hostname;

        jQuery.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            async: false,
            url: gymRegions.ajaxurl,
            data:{action: "showcountries",
                makeselection: "getUserIDs",
                countryID: countryVal,
                cityID: cityVal,
                townID: townVal,
                categoriesID: categoriesVal,
                locationHref: url,
                serialized},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                localStorage.setItem('dataObjectTemp2', JSON.stringify(data));
                var numericRecCount = parseInt(data.c);

                jQuery('#MyForm').submit(function (data) {
                    jQuery.post('', function (data) {
                        document.location.href = window.location.hostname + '/index.php/searchresults/';

                    });
                    return false;
                });
            },
            error: function (data, status, error) {
                alert("No records were returned for your search. Please make another selection.");
                console.log(data);
                console.log(status);
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

```html
function getregions_scripts() {
  wp_enqueue_script(
    'getregions-script',
    plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . "assets/getregions.js",
    array('jquery'),
    '1.0',
    true
  );

  wp_localize_script(
    'getregions-script', 
    'gymRegions',      
    array('ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')) 
  );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'getregions_scripts' );

if ( is_admin() ) {
  add_action( 'wp_ajax_showcountries', 'showcountries_callback' );
  add_action( 'wp_ajax_no_priv_showcountries', 'showcountries_callback' );
  add_action( 'wp_ajax_showcountries_frontend', 'showcountries_frontend' );
  add_action( 'wp_ajax_no_priv_showcountries_frontend', 'showcountries_frontend' );
}else{


}
function showcountries_callback() {

 

 }

function showcountries_frontend() {
$the_html = '

<form id="MyForm" method="Post">
    <div style="float: left">
        <select id="CountryList" onchange="getCities()" style="width: 150px !important; min-width: 150px; max-width: 150px;"></select>
        <select id="CityList" onchange="getTowns()" style="width: 150px !important; min-width: 150px; max-width: 150px;"></select>
        <select id="TownList" style="width: 150px !important; min-width: 150px; max-width: 150px;"></select>
        <select id="CategoriesList" style="width: 170px !important; min-width: 170px; max-width: 170px;"></select>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submitBtn" class="enableOnInput" disabled="disabled" onclick="getUserIDs()" />
</form>';
return $the_html;
}
add_shortcode("sc_frontend", "showcountries_frontend");
```

Plugin2, and it's associated javascript:

```js
(function( $ ) {
  "use strict";

  $(function() {

    $(document).ready(function () {
        feedNewResults();

        function feedNewResults() {
          //$(document).ready(function () {
              var dataObject2 = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('dataObjectTemp2'));

              $('#searchNewCount').append(dataObject2.c);
              $('#searchNewResult').append(dataObject2.q);

        }

        function locationChange(val){
          localStorage.setItem('dataDetailedSearch', JSON.stringify(val));
          window.location.href = window.location.hostname + "/index.php/detailed-search-results/?uid=" + val;
        }

    });

  });

}(jQuery));
```

```html
 function getnewsearchresults_scripts() {

 wp_enqueue_script(
     'getnewsearchresults-script',
     plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . "assets/getnewsearchresults.js",
     array('jquery'),
     '1.0',
     true
   );

   wp_localize_script(
     'getnewsearchresults-script', 
     'resultsNewSearch',      
     array('ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')) 
   );
 }
 add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'getnewsearchresults_scripts' );

 add_action( 'wp_ajax_newsearchresults', 'newsearchresults_callback' );
 add_action( 'wp_ajax_no_priv_newsearchresults', 'newsearchresults_callback' );
```

Now here comes the fun part. If I deactivate plugin 2, plugin 1 works with no issues. But if I leave plugin 2 activated, only the country and category dropdowns of plugin1 are populated. Attempting to select a country to populate the city dropdown with associated country cities, will then not work. This is consistent in all browsers.

How do I resolve this jQuery conflict issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can put a page check before including JS ,

if ($page==='mypluginpage') {
    wp_enqueue_script(
            'getregions-script', plugin_dir_url(**FILE**) . "assets/getregions.js", array('jquery'), '1.0', true
    );
}

Comment: I'm receiving the following error message when I implement your suggestion, `Notice: Undefined variable: page in /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/gyms-of-the-world/gyms-of-the-world.php`. is $page a global variable? And should I be specifying $page==='the actual plugin name.php' or the wordpress page which holds the actual short code, `http://192.0.0.0/index.php/regionspages/`?

Comment: Ok, so I resolved it by doing, global $post;
    if ( in_array( $post->post_name, array( 'testing-2', 'gyms-of-the-world', 'gyms-of-the-world.php' ) ) ){wp_enqueue_script( 'getregions-script', plugin_dir_url(FILE) . "assets/getregions.js", array('jquery'), '1.0', true ); }

Answer (score -1):

Try to use "wp_enqueue_script" function to load jQuery.
It will check if jQuery dose not loaded yet , will load it and if is loaded it dose not do any thing.
This is a sample code of usage for this function.

```
wp_register_script('jquery', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/vendor/jquery-1.11.0.min.js', '1.0.0');
wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); // Enqueue it!
```